# How to tell if a website is using our extension?

Tags: magento2, extensions

We develop Magento extensions. Is there a way to tell what websites are using our extension?

Answer (score 1):

As per said Amit Bera, whatever extensions we installed as global, not as a specific store.

You can also check extension installed or not from the admin/backend.

> Admin Login >> Store >> Store Configuration >> Advanced >> Advanced.

Here you can see the extension name if it installed.

Comment: you have not understand a my question. i have a extension . i sell this extension and how to know which website have installed my extension and also get this website names ?

Answer (score 1):

If your extension is already installed on some website, you cannot figure it out afterwards.

Though you can modify your extension so that whenever someone installs it in the future, you will get to know.

Possibility:

- Modify your website from where people are downloading your module. Add a field to verify website where your module will be used. Once people are entering website url, save it and create a unique licence key for this site.
- Now add a functionality in your Module's admin panel, where they have to enter this licence key, Once they enter the licence key, verify it against the licence key created on your site. If it's successful, you can send customer's website info to your own site and save info their.

This way, you will get to know on which website your module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the installations of your extension and in one way don't want to let host know their installation is tracked, you can use the technique which we often use.

1) You should be collecting the domains when someone buys your extension and explicitly store in one of the database table when order is completed

2) Create an API which passes the data to your website like name of host, extension name, version and last update date. This API should be hosted on your website.

3) In each extension, you use this API and pass the data from where the extension is installed to parent website. You can pass all required information from current host to parent extension website. The event at which the API is called can be decided wisely as per your preference.

4) Compare the entry with the list of domains you have in the database.

This way you can silently observe the extensions installed on different servers and can take necessary actions if any unauthorize of illegal installation is found.

Answer (score -1):

An extension is not installed website or Store wise.

An extension which is installed at the system will act for all websites.

If you want to  check an extension  installed a system then you have run below
at your magento directory.

> php bin/magento module:status {VendorName}_{ModuleName}

where app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName} your module exits.
Or you have to check vendor folder.

Comment: you have not understand a my question. i have a extension . i sell this extension and how to know which website have installed my extension and also get this website names ?